# Should I send recommendation/reference letter to universities that don't require it?

Tags: recommendation-letter

Sending recommendation letter to some universities is optional, but some others don't even mention it in their required documents. Is there any point in sending recommendation letter to such universities?

Comment: I would hope that admissions committees look at supplementary materials when the applicants look the same otherwise on paper rather than flip a coin. That being said, I'm sure someone will bring me down to earth and say "Nope, they don't do that."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm a bit confused since they didn't even ask for a CV and I emailed them and they told me that I can send a CV but that would  absolutely have no effect on my application, so I'm wondering whether the same thing applies to recommendation letters...

Comment: What did they say about letters of recommendations?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't received any reply from them for that, due to holidays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most organizations that have set requirements for applications refuse to look at any supplementary materials that are submitted in order to be fair to those who did not submit supplementary materials. The National Science Foundation, in many cases, reserves the right to return proposals without review that have certain kinds of unrequested or forbidden supplementary materials. I think it's best to only submit what was asked for.

Comment: If they _allow_ you to submit "supplementary materials" without specifying what said materials are, then you can submit the recommendation or not. But if there's no such allowance, don't submit.